# Linux (shell script) csh

Tags: shell-script, csh

I have a code that contain this line:

```
set file = ""    #empty
```

what does it mean?

Comment: This is a `csh` or `tcsh` shell script, right? Not `bash`.

Comment: yes, it is csh , sorry about that

Comment: It's an invalid line of code.

Answer (score 3):

The line comes from a `csh` shell script.  It sets the variable `file` to an empty string.  The `#empty` at the end of the line is a comment. However, the `csh` shell does not like comments in this context and will complain with

```
set: Variable name must begin with a letter.
```

To correct this, move the comment to the line before the assignment:

```
# set 'file' to an empty string
set file=""
```

Comment: It's because you can `set colour="red" shape="square"` and so a comment is not permitted in this context.

Comment: @Christopher what do you mean

Comment: @kusalananda so I have this part of the code like this can you explain the rest please. set files = "" set k = 100 while($k < 210) set files = "$files test$k.ppm" #keep renaming the files #echo "files= $files test$k.ppm" @ k = $k + 10 end

Comment: @fatima Related, on out Meta site: [What else can I do to make my question well-received and improve my chances of getting answers?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5015)

Comment: @Kusalananda so why would we set an empty string file in a code?

Comment: @fatima I have absolutely no idea. It's your code more than mine and I don't know what setting this variable to an empty string does or what happens if it isn't an empty string.